# How to find the fixed points of $\sin(1/x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to find fixed points of the function $\sin(1/x)?$ It seems that there are countable infinite many such points. But how to find these fixed points? I am not getting any idea. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there's a countable infinity of such points -- but what do you mean by "finding" them in this context? You can point out some of them on a graph, or approximate any of them numerically, but I don't think they have any nice analytical expression.

Comment: "Most" of them are near $0$ so $\sin(x)=x$ is near $0$ so $\frac{1}x$ is near a multiple of $\pi$. This can be made into a nice asymptotic result, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=1/x$, then $y\sin y=1$  There are solutions just above $y=2n\pi$ and just below $y=(2n+1)\pi$.  I think you can write them 
$$y_n=2n\pi+\frac{a_1}n+\frac{a_3}{n^3}+\frac{a_5}{n^5}+...$$
then use your knowledge of the MacLaurin series of $\sin x$ to find $a_1,a_3,...$
and then similar for the $(2n+1)\pi$ solutions.